# Custom Route in an App for using in Cloud Shops

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api, shopware6-app

Is it possible to add custom routes in an app which are also valid in a cloud shop? I couldnt find anything about it in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [implement custom endpoints using app scripts](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-scripts/custom-endpoints).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Wasn't sure if this would be the right way to do it.